# Flutter: text only updates after button is tapped twice

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, location

I just started building a weather app in Flutter and I ran into the problem that getting and displaying the user's location as a Text widget requires 2 taps of a FlatButton. I want to make it so that users only have to tap the location FlatButton once for the text to update with their current location. Here's my code (I've cut out unnecessary parts + boilerplate code):

```
class _ClimaState extends State<Clima> {
  Position position;
  List<Placemark> placemark;
  String location;

  void getLocation() async {
    position = await Geolocator()
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.lowest);
    placemark = await Geolocator()
        .placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);

    location = placemark[0].locality + ", " + placemark[0].country;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[

                //I've left out the other children for now

                //This is where I want the user's location to be displayed after they tap the location icon
                Text(
                  placemark != null ? location : "Tap the location icon...",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,

                  ),

                //This is the location icon
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
                  child: FlatButton(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.my_location,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        getLocation();
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out your problem by calling set state the way you are you are not waiting for your `Geolocator` data to return before you rebuild this is why it takes two click to get the data to display. Try this setup

```
  Future<void> getLocation() async {
    position = await Geolocator()
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.lowest);
    placemark = await Geolocator()
        .placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);

    location = placemark[0].locality + ", " + placemark[0].country;
    setState(() {});
  }

//then the onPressed function in your padding widget should be
  onPressed: () async {
              await getLocation();
               },
```